# angular js data binding - global data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template that gets a dynamic title like so:

```
<title>{{title}}</title>
```

for each of my pages(routes) i am using a different controller in which i define the title, like so:

```
BackyApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location, $window, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = 'Home';
});
```

I want to achieve something like the following:

```
$rootScope.title = 'Home' + $rootScope.siteName;
```

What would be the right way to achieve that?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I think I would look at having a service handle this and avoid the `$rootScope` altogether.

Comment: I will look into that, thank you

Comment: which routing library are you using ? `ngRoute` or `ui-router` ?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you try to retrieve the domain name of your site ,so can use  **$location.host();**

your code should be like :

```
$rootScope.title = 'Home' + $location.host();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to define on `global controller` e,g. on body tag.

and  in this you can have your assignment

```
$rootScope.title = 'Home' + $rootScope.siteName;
```